# Can I create a Subscriber Group that can be shared between business units?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm filtering subscribers using Profile Attributes which results in a Group. I need to create this Group in a different business unit than the one from which I'd like to send to it. Is it possible to share this Group between business units? I have shared data extensions and shared publication lists, but I don't see a space for shared Groups.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can share data extensions through shared folders and, indeed, you can share filtered data extension as materialised outputs of your filters in shared folders. Groups cannot be shared. The live in the "My Groups" folder in your business unit with no corresponding shared folder.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the info. I was afraid that was the case.